# Solutions for an 'order respecting' Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

For `Dictionary<,>` "The order in which the items are returned is undefined".

I know there is `SortedDictionary`, but if I just want a dictionary that gives me back the elements in the order I put them in, what is the best thing to do?

I'm thinking that I should use a `List<KeyValuePair<,>>` and convert that to a Dictionary when I need to do a lookup (as opposed to doing a foreach on the Dictionary).

Or am I missing something smarter?

Answer (score 4):

There is a non-generic class that does this: [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) but currenty there is no generic version.

Comment: Thanks, that's something I didn't know about.

Comment: Its not quite the order preserving dictionary. You could insert items into this collection by specifying index in the Insert method, thus altering the meaning of it. I would go for a custom solution here, as it can be guaranteed to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Derive your own collection with a backing dictionary and list that you keep in synch. Whenever items are added/removed you add/remove them to the list and dictionary (same with Clear()). Be sure to check for duplicate keys before adding the items to the list

This would allow you to implement other custom logic like sorting, change notifications, etc